# Visual Studio Code - Unable to launch Browser: "Unable to find an installation of the browser on your system."

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, microsoft-edge

An issue just recently developped while running scripts (any of my scripts in python, javascript,html...) within VS code.  A popup comes up saying: `Visual Studio Code - Unable to launch Browser: "Unable to find an installation of the browser on your system.Try installing it, or providing an absolute path to the browser in the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json.`

My browser is edge. When I open `launch.json` I see that it seems to be attempting to use chrome instead which I do not have downloaded on my computer.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I change the configurations to match the browser I am running on my computer? Or is there something else I can Do to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to change the configurations to launch Edge for debugging. You can refer to [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launch-configuration). You need to change `type` to `pwa-msedge`:

```
"type": "pwa-msedge",
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that's exactly the document I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have one of the browsers specified in

```
.vscode/launch.json
```

I hade two solutions availble to me:

1. Changing the order (have an installed browser as first choice in the file)
2. Install the missing browser

Answer (score 0):

[image: you can just choose on the top to Chrome then it works]

You can just choose on the top to Chrome then it works

Answer (score 0):

***If you use Chrome***, Add runtimeExecutable key value pair in the object inside configurations in launch.json

```
"configurations": [
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
                "url": "http://localhost:3000",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "runtimeExecutable": "/path/to/chrome/executable"

            }
        ]
```