# How do I fix this error on Linux VS Code?

Tags: html, linux, visual-studio-code

I keep getting the following error when I try to launch the debugger for HTML in Chrome: "unable to launch browser. Unable to find an installation of the browser on your system. Try installing it, or providing an absolute path to the browser in the 'runtimeExecutable' in your launch.json."

I'm new to Linux and programming, so I don't really know what this means. I have Chrome installed already, and the .json file I opened up appeared to point to it. I'm confused and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried searching for the answer and asking Linux users.

Comment: Did you check this question and answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931203/visual-studio-code-unable-to-launch-browser-unable-to-find-an-installation-o

Comment: Yes, I did. Although it's similar, it did not answer my question. The .json is configured to Chrome which is what I'm using, because Linux doesn't have the msedge browser.

Answer (score 0):

just change the following in the top and It will work.
[See the Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4eUK.png)

Alternatively,you can to change the configurations to launch the browser. I know for instance in Edge for debugging. You can refer to this doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launch-configuration. You need to change type to pwa-msedge:
"type": "pwa-msedge",

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just using HTML and CSS right now, not react. I'm still very confused.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the instructions, but someone suggested I enable live server, and that sort of worked. It's still not opening in Chrome, though, and I don't have msedge; it's a Linux machine. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: I Will research and solve